# Flash and php params exchange

Tags: flash

Hello 
I am new to flash, and I am trying to make a simple video player. I have a problem setting the source of video: In my action script I have this:

```
player.source='http://localhost/getVideo.php';
```

where getVideo.php is:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('sas.mp4');
?>
```

This works fine but when I try to add some parameters to player.source:

```
player.source='http://localhost/getVideo.php?asd=asdas';
```

i get this error:

```
VideoError: 1005: Invalid xml: URL: "http://localhost/getVideo.php?asd=asdas&FLVPlaybackVersion=2.1" No root node found; if url is for an flv it must have .flv extension and take no parameters
```

What I want to do is, simply to create a player where I can parametrize the video to select.
Any one knows a fast solution to this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously can't attach parameters to the source URL like that.  I couldn't find anything about this in the documentation, but it makes sense to restrict url strings when considering that opening a video file via FLVPlayback is not equal to a simple URL request over a Loader object, but rather involves opening a NetConnection, and then starting and attaching a NetStream, possibly not even over HTTP (which would invalidate URLs with parameters, anyway): The component was not meant for other things - and preventing misuse (even having a dedicated error message) makes sure it works as expected.

Having looked around a bit, it seems you can use [`NetStream.play`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/NetStream.html#play%28%29) in conjunction with a URLRequest, so it might be possible to add GET parameters using [`urlRequest.data`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#data) .  I haven't tried this, though. FLVPlayback's nested [VideoPlayer](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/video/VideoPlayer.html) allows to attach your own stream.

Another solution would be to start a simple URLRequest first, and have your parameterized php script return only the result path for the actual flv movie, which you could then pass to `player.source`.

Comment: Ok i will try the first solution, the second would be the simplest but my webserver doesnt have direct access to my videoserver so i need this method.

Comment: You could also use the webserver's rewrite engine to transform a url into get parameters. Just a thought. ;)